# iOS: How to Push to DetailView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, segue, spotlight

I'm trying to use spotlight results to guide the user to the appropriate section within my app.

The MainView has a few button allowing to go to different areas of the app, one of them being a phone directory, which is inside it's own `SplitViewController`. The `MasterView` has the list of users in a `TableView` and the `DetailView` has the item details.

Currently, I have the following in my `AppDelegate.m`.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler {
    if ([userActivity.activityType isEqualToString:CSSearchableItemActionType]) {

        // uid = an Id field unique for each record
        NSString *uid = userActivity.userInfo[CSSearchableItemActivityIdentifier];

        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *navController = nil;
        navController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PhoneDirectory"];

        if (navController != nil) {
            [[[self window] rootViewController] presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Here is my structure, hopefully it does a good job illustrating it.

```
Navigation Controller
|
|-- Main View
    |-- About View
    |
    |-- SplitView Controller (StoryboardID: PhoneDirectory)
        |-- Master View Controller
        |-- Detail View Controller
    |--Another View
```

What I want is to present the `DetailView` with the information of the user. On devices which show the `MasterView` and `DetailView` I would like the `MasterView` to look as if the row was tapped.

What's the best way i can accomplish this? How do I pass the **uid** to the `MasterView` and then mimic a tap to simulate a touch on the appropriate row.

**Note:** my data at the `MasterView` is setup as a `Dictionary` of `Arrays`, in case that matters in how to find the proper user by **uid**.

If you need further information, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `MasterViewController.h`

```
-(void)selectRowWithID:(NSString*)uid;
```

Inside `MasterViewController.m`

```
-(void)selectRowWithID:(NSString*)uid
    {
        NSPredicate* predicate = nil;
        //Your logic to find the match from array;

    NSArray* matches = [dataSourceArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    if([matches count] > 0)
    {
        NSDictionary* match = matches[0];

        NSIndexPath* targetIndexPath;
        // Your logic to find out the indexPath for this match


        // Ask the table to select the row programatically
        [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:targetIndexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];

        // Manually forward the event for this, as if user touched the cell
        // SDK won't forward this method call for programmatic cell selections
        [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:targetIndexPath];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"'uid' not found in the master table dataSource");
    }
}
```

This has been working out great for me for most of my projects.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. But how do I call this method? The `AppDelegate`? The `navController` references the `SplitViewController`. When I try to use `PhoneDirectoryMasterViewController *master = [[navController viewControllers] firstObject]; [master selectRowWithId:uid];` after `presentViewController` I get an error `-[UINavigationController selectRowWithId:]: unrecognized selector`.

Comment: Ok I tried this and seems to work, but is it the correct way to get the master view? `PhoneDirectoryMasterViewController *master = [[[[navController viewControllers] firstObject] childViewControllers] firstObject];`

Comment: @RoLYroLLs Yes, you need to get through to your `masterViewController` via traversing into the `UISplitViewController` hierarchy. As the solution works, would you please mark it as the correct answer? It may be helpful for some other fellow developer.

Comment: Yes I will mark it as correct answer I was just waiting to make sure I was calling the `masterViewController` correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, can you take a look at my followup question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37799181/how-to-properly-present-data-from-core-spotlight-and-nsuseractivity. Thanks.

Comment: @RoLYroLLs I just added an answer to the second question from you.