# How to Properly Present Data from Core Spotlight and NSUserActivity

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm trying to use spotlight results to guide the user to the appropriate section within my app.

Here is my structure, hopefully it does a good job illustrating it.

```
Navigation Controller
|
|-- Main View
    |-- About View
    |
    |-- SplitView Controller (Presented Modally;StoryboardID: PhoneDirectory)
        |-- Master View Controller
        |-- Detail View Controller
    |--Another View
```

When a search result brings the user to my app **the first time** all works well. I am able to present the `SplitViewController` and then send the user to the appropriate `DetailView`.

However, if the user leaves the app at it's current state and goes back to the search and the taps on another result, the user is taken back to the app with the previous view loaded.

I'm not sure how to go about it at this point.

- Do I `pop` the previous view? If so, how?
- Do I reload the data in the detail view? If so, how?
- How can I identify that I'm already presenting a view that I need to present with different data?

With the code below I get the following warning, on the 2nd search result selection:

`Warning: Attempt to present <PhoneDirectorySplitViewController: 0x7fdf398ab600> on <UINavigationController: 0x7fdf3c831600> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Here's the code I have so far (condensed)

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler {
    NSString *uid = nil;
    if ([[userActivity activityType] isEqualToString:CSSearchableItemActionType] || [[userActivity activityType] isEqualToString:@"com.myapp.activity"]) {
        uid = [userActivity userInfo][CSSearchableItemActivityIdentifier];
    }

    if (uid != nil) {
        NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        f.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
        NSNumber *idNum = [f numberFromString:uid];

        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *navController = nil;
        navController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PhoneDirectory"];

        if (navController != nil) {
            [[[self window] rootViewController] presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
            PhoneDirectoryMasterViewController *master = [[[[navController viewControllers] firstObject] childViewControllers] firstObject];
            [master selectRowWithId:idNum];

            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

**MasterView.h**

```
- (void)selectRowWithId:(NSNumber *)uid {
    [[self displayedPersons] enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull key, id  _Nonnull obj, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(id == %@)", uid];
        NSArray *filteredPersonsArray = [obj filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        if ([filteredPersonsArray count] > 0) {
            NSIndexPath *targetIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[[[self displayedPersons] objectForKey:key] indexOfObject:filteredPersonsArray[0]] inSection:[[self personIndexTitles] indexOfObject:key]];

            [[self tableView] selectRowAtIndexPath:targetIndexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showPhoneDirectoryDetail" sender:self];
        }
    }];
}
```

If you need more info, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some validations checks at proper places. Add this declaration to your `AppDelegate.m`

```
UISplitViewController *splitViewController;
```

You might need to keep a reference to the `splitViewController` as you need to access it the second time and you must not create a new controller instance every time you need the same. Currently you are creating a new `splitViewController` instance every time you come back to app from outside.

#### Check #1

```
if(splitViewController == nil)
{
    // Only create a new splitViewController if it's not have been created already
    splitViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PhoneDirectory"];
}
```

#### Check #2

```
// presentingViewController points to the base viewController that presented it
    if(splitViewController.presentingViewController == nil)
    {
        // Only present splitViewController is it's not been presented already
        [[[self window] rootViewController] presentViewController:splitViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

#### Check #3 (Inside your MasterViewController.m 'selectRowWithId:')

```
// Finally before making the push with new instance, just pop the old one out of the navigationStack
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showPhoneDirectoryDetail" sender:self];
```

That'd be all you need. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out. I did try adding some code for removing `presentedViewController` and `popViewController`, but I think you are right that I need to first reference the `UISplitViewController` because I would always get `nil`. Also, I have button which opens the `UISplitViewController` and a user can navigate to the `detailViewController` that way and then launch the app from search. Will this take care of that too or will I need to do more? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure this is working or I'm not implementing it correctly.

Comment: @RoLYroLLs I'm not sure about how your design(button for navigation to splitViewController) works. The code should be working given the case in your question. What problems are you facing?

Comment: @RoLYroLLs if your old instance for detailViewController can't pop out properly in each case. Try setting the 'animated:NO' in the pop call. If it still doesn't work out, try to add a bit delay in the push action 0.1-0.2 seconds.

Comment: A button on `MainViewController` has a `segue` in IB to the `PhoneDirectorySplitViewController`. `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` states `Property 'navigationController' not found on object of Type 'AppDelegate *'`. And `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showPhoneDirectoryDetail" sender:self];` gives me `No visible @interface for 'AppDelegate' declares the selector 'performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:'`

Comment: You need to do the '3rd Check' code inside 'selectRowWithId:' method. It will work. I didn't mention it clearly where to put that code earlier.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I put the code where I think you are asking me to, but it's not working. The very first time I click on a search item it opens properly now. However, when I click on the second item, the view is not `popping`.

Answer (score -1):

So after looking through many SO questions/answers here's what I've come up with. It might not be universally, but it works. If someone can make it universal please feel free to submit a new answer.

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler {
    NSString *uid = nil;
    if ([[userActivity activityType] isEqualToString:CSSearchableItemActionType] || [[userActivity activityType] isEqualToString:@"com.myapp.activity"]) {
        uid = [userActivity userInfo][CSSearchableItemActivityIdentifier];
    }

    if (uid != nil) {
        NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        f.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
        NSNumber *idNum = [f numberFromString:uid];

        UIViewController *vc = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] presentedViewController];

        if ([vc class] == [PhoneDirectorySplitViewController class]) {
            if ([vc respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:)]) {
                [vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
                    [self showUserActivity:idNum];
                }];
            }
        } else if ([vc class] == [UINavigationController class]) {
            if ([vc respondsToSelector:@selector(visibleViewController)]) {
                if ([[(UINavigationController *)vc visibleViewController] respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:)]) {
                    [[(UINavigationController *)vc visibleViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
                        [self showUserActivity:idNum];
                    }];
                }
            }
        } else {
            [self showUserActivity:idNum];
        }

        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}

- (void)showUserActivity:(NSNumber *)idNum {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navController = nil;
    navController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PhoneDirectory"];

    if (navController != nil) {
        [[[self window] rootViewController] presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
        PhoneDirectoryMasterViewController *master = [[[[navController viewControllers] firstObject] childViewControllers] firstObject];
        [master selectRowWithId:idNum];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is completely wrong. You should delete this answer. It will mislead other developers. You are still making duplicate instances here - 'navController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PhoneDirectory"];'